# Symfony routing is not working?

Tags: php, symfony1, routes, url-routing

I am working on existing project. I have following two URLs

```
http://example.dev/en/course/myUserName/myCourseName/150/myChapterName/1016/page/1/?hcid=147

http://example.dev/en/course/myUserName/myCourseName/150/myChapterName/1016/page/2/?hcid=147
```

2nd URL is working fine but 1st URL is giving me following **error**:

```
Unable to find a matching route to generate url for params "array (  'action' => 'showChapter',  'module' => 'course',  'courseowner' => 'myUserName',  'coursename' => 'myCourseName',  'courseid' => '150',  'chaptername' => 'myChapterName',)"., 
referer: http://example.dev/en/course/myUserName/myCourseName/150/myChapterName/1016/page/1/?hcid=147
```

I have following entry in **routing.yml**:

```
course_chapter:
  url: /:sf_culture/course/:courseowner/:coursename/:courseid/:chaptername/:chapterid/:page/:pageid/
  param: { module: course, action: showChapter }
  requirements:
      courseid: \d+
```

**url_for():**

```
<?php $headchapter = ($hcid) ? '?hcid='.$hcid : '' ?>
<a href="<?php echo url_for('course/showChapter?courseowner='.$sf_params->get("courseowner").'&coursename='.$sf_params->get("coursename").'&courseid='.$sf_params->get("courseid").'&chaptername='.$chapter->getName().'&chapterid='.$chapter->getId().'&page=page&pageid=1').$headchapter ?>">
```

I cant understand how it is working for 2nd URL and not for first URL. I have checked the action and view and I did not find any error.

Any Idea or debugging technique ??

Comment: Please post also the code of your `url_for` function which have to generate the url

Comment: @osamson: I have added `url_for()` code into question. Here `$hcid=147`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do your links like that. There is a cleaner way.

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('course/showChapter?courseowner='.$sf_params->get("courseowner").'&coursename='.$sf_params->get("coursename").'&courseid='.$sf_params->get("courseid").'&chaptername='.$chapter->getName().'&chapterid='.$chapter->getId().'&page=page&pageid=1').$headchapter ?>">
```

Do this instead:

```
link_to("Link text","course_chapter",array("courseowner"=>$sf_params->get("courseowner"),
                                           "coursename"=>$sf_params->get("coursename"),
                                           "courseid"=>$sf_params->get("courseid"),
                                           "chaptername"=>$chapter->getName(),
                                           "chapterid"=>$chapter->getId(),
                                           "pageid"=>1,
                                           "hcid"=>$hcid))
```

If a param doesn't exist in your routing url, it'll get appended like `?hcid=2`
Why are you using `sf_params` to generate the URL params and not the database? i.e why is it `$sf_params->get('courseid')` and not `$course->getId()` from a doctrine object?

Also instead of using `course/showChapter` use the route id of `course_chapter`

I'd advise that you go back to the symfony manual and re-read the routing section.

EDIT:

In your route definition, you have:

`url: /:sf_culture/course/:courseowner/:coursename/:courseid/:chaptername/:chapterid/:page/:pageid/`

why is page a parameter if it's always the same value, i.e. it's always gonna be page.

This would be better:

`url: /:sf_culture/course/:courseowner/:coursename/:courseid/:chaptername/:chapterid/page/:pageid/`

And don't `chapterid` and `pageid` need to be part of the requirements of `\d+` too?

Comment: +1 for your suggestions and hard work. Let me figure out this. Thanks